# Silverlight double color lines

Tags: silverlight, drawing, lines

I need to draw a line with two adjacent color. 
The only solution i found is based on two lines, with a TranslateTransform on the second.
But the translate value have to change according to line orientation (angle).

Is the any way to do it more easily?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw a two-colour line using a LinearGradientBrush with four GradientStops.  For example, the following XAML draws a horizontal line that is half red and half yellow:

```
    <Line X1="0" Y1="20" X2="200" Y2="20" StrokeThickness="14">
        <Line.Stroke>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Red" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Red" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Yellow" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Yellow" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Line.Stroke>
    </Line>
```

If you attempt to use the same LinearGradientBrush with a line that is not horizontal, you will quickly find that it won't do what you want.  The two colours are always separated by a horizontal line whatever gradient the line has, whereas you want the line that separates the two colours to run down the middle of your `Line`.  To achieve this, you need to change the `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` for the LinearGradientBrush.  These depend on the gradient of the line, and they are a little awkward to calculate.

To demonstrate how this can be done, I've put together a templated control (below) that draws two-colour lines.  `Color1` is the colour that would be on your left if you stood at (`X1`, `Y1`) and looked towards (`X2`, `Y2`), and `Color2` would be on your right.

Note that this control assumes that the start and end caps of the line are `Flat`.   If you wish to use other types of start or end cap (e.g. `Square` or `Round`), you will need to adjust the calculation of `overallWidth` and `overallHeight`.

TwoColorLine.cs:

```
public class TwoColorLine : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty X1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("X1", typeof(double), typeof(TwoColorLine), new PropertyMetadata(Coordinates_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Y1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Y1", typeof(double), typeof(TwoColorLine), new PropertyMetadata(Coordinates_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty X2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("X2", typeof(double), typeof(TwoColorLine), new PropertyMetadata(Coordinates_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Y2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Y2", typeof(double), typeof(TwoColorLine), new PropertyMetadata(Coordinates_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Color1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Color1", typeof(Color), typeof(TwoColorLine), new PropertyMetadata(Colors_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Color2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Color2", typeof(Color), typeof(TwoColorLine), new PropertyMetadata(Colors_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(TwoColorLine), null);

    private LinearGradientBrush lineBrush;

    public TwoColorLine()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TwoColorLine);
    }

    public double X1
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(X1Property); }
        set { SetValue(X1Property, value); }
    }

    public double Y1
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(Y1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Y1Property, value); }
    }

    public double X2
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(X2Property); }
        set { SetValue(X2Property, value); }
    }

    public double Y2
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(Y2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Y2Property, value); }
    }

    public Color Color1
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(Color1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Color1Property, value); }
    }

    public Color Color2
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(Color2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Color2Property, value); }
    }

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void Coordinates_Changed(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var line = obj as TwoColorLine;
        if (line != null)
        {
            line.OnCoordinatesChanged();
        }
    }

    private static void Colors_Changed(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var line = obj as TwoColorLine;
        if (line != null)
        {
            line.OnColorsChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnCoordinatesChanged()
    {
        if (lineBrush != null)
        {
            RecalculateEndPoints();
        }
    }

    public void OnColorsChanged()
    {
        if (lineBrush != null)
        {
            UpdateColors();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateColors()
    {
        lineBrush.GradientStops[0].Color = Color1;
        lineBrush.GradientStops[1].Color = Color1;
        lineBrush.GradientStops[2].Color = Color2;
        lineBrush.GradientStops[3].Color = Color2;
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Line line = GetTemplateChild("line") as Line;
        if (line == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No line found in the template");
        }

        lineBrush = line.Stroke as LinearGradientBrush;
        if (lineBrush == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Line does not have a LinearGradientBrush as its stroke");
        }

        UpdateColors();
        RecalculateEndPoints();
    }

    private void RecalculateEndPoints()
    {
        double cos, sin;
        if (X2 == X1)
        {
            cos = 0;
            sin = (Y2 > Y1) ? 1 : -1;
        }
        else
        {
            double gradient = (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1);
            cos = Math.Sqrt(1 / (1 + gradient * gradient));
            sin = gradient * cos;
        }

        // These two lines assume flat start and end cap.
        double overallWidth = Math.Abs(X2 - X1) + StrokeThickness * Math.Abs(sin);
        double overallHeight = Math.Abs(Y2 - Y1) + StrokeThickness * Math.Abs(cos);

        int sign = (X2 < X1) ? -1 : 1;

        double xOffset = (sign * StrokeThickness * sin / 2) / overallWidth;
        double yOffset = (sign * StrokeThickness * cos / 2) / overallHeight;

        lineBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0.5 + xOffset, 0.5 - yOffset);
        lineBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0.5 - xOffset, 0.5 + yOffset);
    }
}
```

Themes\Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="local:TwoColorLine">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TwoColorLine">
                <Line x:Name="line" X1="{TemplateBinding X1}" Y1="{TemplateBinding Y1}" X2="{TemplateBinding X2}" Y2="{TemplateBinding Y2}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding StrokeThickness}">
                    <Line.Stroke>
                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Line.Stroke>
                </Line>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Example usage:

```
<Grid>
    <local:TwoColorLine X1="190" Y1="170" X2="150" Y2="50" Color1="Red" Color2="Green" StrokeThickness="14" />
    <local:TwoColorLine X1="210" Y1="170" X2="250" Y2="50" Color1="Red" Color2="Green" StrokeThickness="14" />
    <local:TwoColorLine X1="230" Y1="190" X2="350" Y2="150" Color1="Red" Color2="Green" StrokeThickness="14" />
    <local:TwoColorLine X1="230" Y1="210" X2="350" Y2="250" Color1="Red" Color2="Green" StrokeThickness="14" />
    <local:TwoColorLine X1="210" Y1="230" X2="250" Y2="350" Color1="Red" Color2="Green" StrokeThickness="14" />
    <local:TwoColorLine X1="190" Y1="230" X2="150" Y2="350" Color1="Red" Color2="Green" StrokeThickness="14" />
    <local:TwoColorLine X1="170" Y1="210" X2="50" Y2="250" Color1="Red" Color2="Green" StrokeThickness="14" />
    <local:TwoColorLine X1="170" Y1="190" X2="50" Y2="150" Color1="Red" Color2="Green" StrokeThickness="14" />
</Grid>
```

**EDIT**: revise `RecalculateEndPoints()` method to put the StartPoint and EndPoint on the edge of the line rather than on the line's bounding rectangle.  The revised method is much simpler and makes it easier to use the control with more than two colours.

Comment: Now i'm trying to add a transparent separator between the two lines. I suppose i have to add a transparent gradient stop. Moreover i need to make the two lines thinckess to be variable, depending on bound values. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think i need a three colors line with a middle transparent color. I'm trying to get it, but i'm not able to manage the width on the lines.

Comment: @Nino: I've edited the control to make it easier to adapt to multiple colours.  The StartPoint and EndPoint are now on the edge of the line so that the visible range of Offset values is 0 to 1 instead of some small range either side of 0.5 that depends on the orientation.  To add a transparent colour down the middle, it should be enough to add two GradientStops to the middle of the LinearGradientBrush's GradientStops collection, and also update the indexes in the `UpdateColors()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small ImageBrush with the colors, and draw a single line using it.

Comment: Silverlight doesn't support tiling image brushes. I'm afraid this solution could not be applicable.

Comment: Huh - looks like others have encountered that as well.  Using a shader appears to be the workaround others have employed, e.g. http://silverscratch.blogspot.com/2010/09/tiled-image-brush-for-silverlight.html